# primefaces: outputpanel in dialog can't fit into scrollPanel

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

i have complex dialog box where is p:scrollPannel, and when I scrolling down to the bottom, last component  doesn't fit into modal window.

Here is my code:

```
<p:dialog header="Edit Invoice" 
      widgetVar="changeInvoiceDialog" 
      showEffect="clip"
      hideEffect="fold" 
      id="paidDialog" 
      minHeight="200"
      minWidth="200"
      appendToBody="true">
<h:form id="payInvoiceForm">
    <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="payment" value="#{newPayment.paymentType}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Paid by Credit Card" itemValue="CARD"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Paid by Check" itemValue="CHECK"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Paid by Wire" itemValue="WIRE"/>
            <p:ajax update="done paymentType"/>
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{newPayment.isPurchaseOrder(invoiceViewer.currentInvoice.payment) == false}">
            ...
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:outputPanel id="paymentType">
// here is the problem
            <p:scrollPanel rendered="#{newPayment.paymentType == 'CARD'}" style="height:200px">
                <nm:outputCreditCardInformation />
                <nm:outputBillingAddressInformation contact="#{invoiceViewer.currentInvoice.contact}"/>
            </p:scrollPanel>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{newPayment.paymentType == 'CHECK' or newPayment.paymentType == 'WIRE'}">
                ...
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="done" .../>
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Here is how it's looks.

[image]

Any idea how to fix it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why you fixed Scrollpane  is `height:200px;`

Comment: Otherwise it will take screen until bottom, and i want to keep nice and tidy dialog box.

Comment: @RobertasUldukis try `<h:panelGrid cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">` and see if it has any effect. Or `style="height:200px; margin-bottom:15px;"`

Comment: @Martin Metsalu, I did try and margin and padding. Already spending more then 4h with this bug, browsing, experimenting with css, nothing helps.